# ColdFusion Loops to Seemingly Different Times in Same Code

Tags: loops, time, coldfusion

Consider the following loop:

```
<cfloop from="#timeFormat(roomAvail.startTime,'short')#" to="#timeFormat(roomAvail.endTime,'short')#" step="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)#" index="time">
    <cfoutput>
        #timeFormat(time,'short')#<br/>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

When my input is from:`9:00 AM` to:`8:00 PM` the code outputs every 30 min increment from 9:00 AM to 7:30 PM.

When my input is from:`10:00 AM` to:`1:00 PM` the code outputs every 30 min increment form 10:00 AM to 1:00 PM.

Can anyone explain what is happening and why there is one 30 min segment missing from the first loop and not the second? I was told this was a valid method of looping over times, but I'm starting to think that because the time is rendered as a float in the underlying Java method, some rounding is occurring and it's screwing up.

Edit: I really don't think it matters that I'm not passing in Date/Time objects. CF is casting that behind the scenes, otherwise the entire thing wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be because under the hood, all CF is doing is converting the Dates to Doubles (or in your case: the Strings to Dates to Doubles), and 8pm (20/24ths of 1 day) will have a rounding error which leaves it within the intended upper boundary; whereas 1pm (13/24ths of 1 day) is slighty outside the intended upper boundary.

It probably doesn't help that you're passing a string when the loop is expecting dates.

Comment: I took this from here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/684-looping-over-times-in-coldfusion.htm as I couldn't find a great way to loop over times. Do you have a great alternative?

Comment: Marked as answer since my question wasn't for a solution but a reason as to why.

Comment: @Leeish try passing in actual date objects instead of strings. I know you're only looping over times, but perhaps create them as date objects using some apprropriate date (today? The day that the timespan is relevant too? Impossible to say without context). Sorry - and I hope this doesn't seem rude or dismissive - but I don't have time-resource at the moment to investigate @ give you a model answer.

Comment: @AdamCameron - While the use of timeFormat is not great practice, switching to Date objects probably will not make a difference here. As soon as you start looping with a time span object (double), the index becomes a Double as well. Makes me wonder why the heck docs recommend using an approximate for date math, given that it is an approximate type.  Though personally, I have always preferred using date functions for date logic.

Answer (score 0):

timeFormat returns a string. Could you use createTime instead to use a proper time object, as per their example in the docs?

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfloop%3A+looping+over+a+date+or+time+range

```
<cfset startTime = CreateTime(9,0,0)> 
<cfset endTime = CreateTime(20,0,0)> 
<cfloop from="#startTime#" to="#endTime#" index="time" step="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)#"> 
    <cfoutput>#TimeFormat(time, "short")#<br /></cfoutput>
</cfloop>

<cfset startTime = CreateTime(10,0,0)> 
<cfset endTime = CreateTime(13,0,0)> 
<cfloop from="#startTime#" to="#endTime#" index="time" step="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)#"> 
    <cfoutput>#TimeFormat(time, "short")#<br /></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

**Update:** The above code didn't solve your problem.  You could do this instead.  Looping to the second previous means you always miss out on that end time.  Then, assuming you want to display the end, add that in after the loop:

```
<cfset startTime = CreateTime(9,0,0)> 
<cfset endTime = CreateTime(19,59,59)> 
<cfloop from="#startTime#" to="#endTime#" index="time" step="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)#"> 
    <cfoutput>#TimeFormat(time, "short")#<br /></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>#TimeFormat(dateAdd("s", 1, endTime), "short")#<br /></cfoutput>


<cfset startTime = CreateTime(10,0,0)> 
<cfset endTime = CreateTime(12,59,59)> 
<cfloop from="#startTime#" to="#endTime#" index="time" step="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)#"> 
    <cfoutput>#TimeFormat(time, "short")#<br /></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>#TimeFormat(dateAdd("s", 1, endTime), "short")#<br /></cfoutput>
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  If you tried DateTime objects instead of TimeObjects, do you get the hoped for results?  They would be more appropriate anyway because it's conceivable that the date might change inside the loop.

Comment: From what I gather, CF does this behind the scenes for me. It's smart like that. I think Adam hit the nail on the head about the rounding error. You adjusting to seconds is just "fixing" the rounding error I think.

Comment: Don't trust CF to always do things for you.  My experience is that as the version gets higher, forgiveness of code inperfections gets lower.