# Display single digits with leading zero

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to make a minutes dropdown. How do I make it come out as `01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07 08, 09, 10, 11, 12`, etc.? Right now the first 9 numbers only come out as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`.

```
<select id="minutes">
  <cfloop from="1" to="60" index="m">
    <option>#m#</option>
  </cfloop>
</select>
```

Well, I understand why it's doing what it's doing and was expecting it anyway. Haha. Just wondered if there was a way of getting the 0s to come up without having to manually create 01-09 options.

Comment: Not related to your question but, depending on things that only you know, it might make more sense to loop from 0-59 instead of 1-60.

Comment: Side note, the [Functions by Category](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Display+and+formatting+functions) view of the documentation is your friend ;-)

Comment: @DanBracuk Great catch! I did not notice that! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`numberFormat`](http://cfdocs.org/numberformat).

```
<select id="minutes">
    <cfoutput>
        <cfloop from="1" to="60" index="m">
            <option>#numberFormat(m,'00')#</option>
        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
</select>
```

See also this [runnable example](http://trycf.com/editor/gist/7d05e5d3db7a036ff1ab?theme=solarized_dark) at [trycf.com](http://trycf.com).

Comment: Awesome! :) Thanks for that link to trycf as well! Very useful! :)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options off the top of my head:

**Option 1 - cfloop over timespan**

Create a start and end time, and use cfloop with a step value of one minute (source: [adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-71a9.html) )

```
<cfset startTime = CreateTime(0,0,0)>
<cfset endTime = CreateTime(0,59,59)>
<select id="minutes">
  <cfoutput>
    <cfloop from="#startTime#" to="#endtime#" index="m" step="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,1,0)#">
      <option>#TimeFormat(m, 'mm')#</option>
    </cfloop>
  </cfoutput>
</select>
```

**Option 2 - use RIGHT()**

Just prepend 0 to all values, and take the right two characters:

```
<select id="minutes">
  <cfoutput>
    <cfloop from="0" to="59" index="m">
        <option>#Right(0 & m, 2)#</option>
    </cfloop>
  </cfoutput>
</select>
```

Comment: I prefer Option 2 because it's simpler.

Comment: Though it probably makes no difference in this case, personally I would avoid using creatTimeSpan for loops. Internally it is stored as an approximate type, so [rounding can lead to unexpected results in some cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29214873/104223).

Comment: Good call about rounding issues. I typically wouldn't advocate for Option 1, but just put it out there. I prefer Option 2 because it's much simpler as well.

However, @Abram's solution using numberFormat() is the best. I always forget about that function.