# How to create JSON from cfquery?

Tags: javascript, json, date, coldfusion

Here is my query that I put in JSON and after that store information in the table. When I checked results in the table I saw that output does not give me what i actually wanted. My idea is to get all dates in between each start and end date. My code gave me just end dates. Here is my code:

```
//Here is my query 
<cfquery name="myQuery" datasource="test">
    Select UserID, UserEmail, PickDateTime, DropDateTime
    From UserInfo
    Order by PickDateTime
</cfquery>

//This is my JSON 
<script>
    myJSON = {
    <cfoutput query="myQuery">
        <cfloop from="#PickDateTime#" to="#DropDateTime#" index="i" step="#CreateTimeSpan(1,0,0,0)#">
           "#currentrow#":{"ID":"#UserID#","date":"#dateformat(i,'mmddyyyy')#","email":"#UserEmail#"},  
        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
    }

//Here is my function that creates the table
function getData(){
    myVar="<table><tr><td>ID</td><td>Date</td><td>Email</td></tr><tbody>"
    for(key in myJSON){
        myVar+=
            "<tr>"+
            "<td>"+myJSON[key].ID+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+myJSON[key].date+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+myJSON[key].email+"</td>"+
            "</tr>"
    }
    myVar+="</tbody></table>"
    document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = myVar    
}
</script>
```

and here is my html:

```
<div id='myTable'></div>
```

Here is my table with current output:

```
ID   Date          Email
1   01092016    example@gmail.com
2   01112016    example@gmail.com
3   01132016    example@gmail.com
3   01162016    example@gmail.com
4   01182016    example@gmail.com
5   01192016    example@gmail.com
```

As you can see in my output I'm just getting End dates but I do not get dates in between. I should get all dates from start to end date. If my start date is 01/20/2015 and my end date is 01/24/2015 I want to have dates in between. I'm not sure if my JSON is created properly or something is wrong in my cfloop. If anyone can help with this problem please let me know.

Comment: If you dump your query results do you see all the records you expect?

Comment: Can ColdFusion really loop over a variable with dates? `<cfloop from="#PickDateTime#" to="#DropDateTime#" index="i" step="#CreateTimeSpan(1,0,0,0)#">` That just looks suspect

Comment: @JamesAMohler - Yes, it works because date objects are numbers internally. Well ... *mostly* works. When used in combination with createTimeSpan, the index is converted `java.lang.Double` creating [subtle rounding issues in some cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29214873/104223).  Personally, I avoid it and use integer loops + date functions instead.

Comment: @user3023588 - It seems like your recent threads have explained [*how* you are trying to solve some unknown task, without having explained what that task is first](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174378).  There may be simpler options, but it is hard to suggest options without a clear end goal. What exactly is the  ultimate goal (populate a calendar, etcetera...) ? Also, what are the contents of `myQuery`? Do a cfdump of the query and post a screen shot OR use http://trycf.com to [post a sample query](http://trycf.com/gist/a61a9c7cd62cdb413b4d/acf11?theme=monokai).

Comment: What version of  ColdFusion  are you using? in CF10: SerializeJSON may results in invalid json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to convert  ColdFusion data into a JSON is using the `SerializeJSON()` function.

Supported since ColdFusion 8. [See SerializeJSON](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-79fa.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

**SerializeJSON:** Converts ColdFusion data into a JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) representation of the data.Returns a string that contains a JSON representation of the parameter value.

But if you are using **[ColdFusion 10: SerializeJSON may results in invalid json](https://www.hass.de/content/coldfusion-10-serializejson-may-results-invalid-json)**.

```
<cfscript>
    // Create an input string that has two different uses of the "u" character.
    input = "Hello \u1111 u+2222 world";
    // Output the original value.
    writeOutput( input & "<br />" );
    // Output the serialized value produced by serializeJson().
    // CAUTION: The "u+" string will be accidentally replaced with "\u".
    writeOutput( serializeJson( input ) );
</cfscript>
```

To avoid this and to make it run in any ColdFusion version you can do this:

```
<cfscript>
    input = "\\u+1234 hello \u1111 , \u+2222 , u+2222 world";
    writeOutput( input & "<br />" );
    serializedInput = serializeJson( input );
    writeOutput( serializedInput & "<br />" );
    savecontent variable = "pattern" {
        writeOutput( "(?x)" );
        writeOutput( "( ^ | [^\\] | (?: \\ \\ )+ )" );
        writeOutput( "\\u" );
    }

    safeOutput = javaCast( "string", serializedInput ).replaceAll(
        javaCast( "string", pattern ),
        javaCast( "string", "$1u+" )
    );


    writeOutput( safeOutput & "<br />" );
    writeOutput( deserializeJson( safeOutput ) );
</cfscript>
```

[REFERENCE](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2842-serializejson-and-the-input-and-output-encodings-are-not-same-errors-in-coldfusion.htm)